# update folder and track complete state via git?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I'm using Git on Mac OS X. I want to update a php plugin/extension in typo3. Actually these are php files in folders.
I created a new branch for this.

The update for this php plugin contains changed php files, new php files and delete files because in the new script some files are not needed any more.

I deleted the whole folder and afterwards i copied the new folder content inside. 
Ok so far, `git status` has some new, some modified and some deleted files found.

When I commit these changes and switch back to the origin branch, then all new files are also available here!

Is that the normal behaviour, and, if som, how can I totally seperated file/folder structure and content for each branch?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the commands you typed to commit the files

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you forgot to `git add` the new files before doing `git commit`.  In that case the files would not have been added to a commit on the branch.

`git checkout` somewhat confusingly will bring both modified and untracked files with you when you switch between branches.  So if you forgot to add the files and commit them, then it is expected that they would still show up in `git status` after you switched branches.